# Azure servicebus listener on nestjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, nestjs, azureservicebus

I have one service which handles business logic for my product.

I need to call that service as and when i receive a message through service bus on azure.

I am able to pick the message from azure service bus queue using azure npm package. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues

But when message reached in my app, i am unable to inject the business logic class to the above listener. We are using NestJS framework.

Tech Details: NestJS, NodeJs, Typescript, Azure service bus

Comment: Did you look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pebula/nesbus

Comment: Could you please elaborate what is your goal and what problem you are facing with some code which you have tried, instead of providing link so that I can help by doing repro of your problem.

Comment: You can refer to [NesBus (Nest / Service Bus) is a microservice extension for NestJS](https://shlomiassaf.github.io/pebula-node/nesbus/docs/getting-started/introduction/) and open an issue on GitHub: [azure-sdk-for-js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues)

Answer (score 1):

Posting Suggestion provided by [Jesse-Carter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364771/jesse-carter) as an answer so that it will be helpful for other community members who face similar kind of issues.

**NesBus** (Nest / Service Bus) is a microservice extension for **NestJS** that adds support for Azure Service Bus within **NestJS** in a simple and intuitive way.

#### Message Handling

Handling incoming service bus message is now as easy as handling incoming REST requests.

```
@Controller()

export  class  ServiceBusController  {

 @Queue<MethodDecorator>(({

 name:  'nesbus-queue.demo'

 })

 async  myQueueEntity(@Ctx()  context: SbContext)  {

 }

}
```

for more information check the [NesBus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pebula/nesbus).

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: The issue with NesBus is that it does not look like maintained anymore